# Refresh Css on List when one of the Item is Removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

Im new to Google Maps and i have created a List that shows the Markers on Bounds but when the Marker is out of bounds  the Css or the Background of the item removed on list still remains and the Items Remaining on List have the same background color because it is not refresh. .

Here is the Image of my Maps and List Before and After The item is not on Bounds

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Here is the set of Codes :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder, infoBubble;
        var map;
        //var mgr;

        function initialize() {
            var minZoomLevel = 4;
            var zooms = 7;
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: minZoomLevel,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            // Bounds for North America
            var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

            // Listen for the dragend event
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

                // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

                var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

                if (x < minX) x = minX;
                if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
                if (y < minY) y = minY;
                if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
            });


            // Limit the zoom level
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
            });



        }
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        function codeAddress() {
            infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                map: map,
                shadowStyle: 0,
                padding: 10,
                borderRadius: 10,
                arrowSize: 15,
                maxWidth: 300,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#ccc',
                arrowPosition: 50,
                arrowStyle: 0
            });
            $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function Geocode(address) {
                $.each(address, function () {
                    var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
                    var Name = this["Name"];
                    var Gender = this["Gender"];
                    var Bdate = this["Birthdate"];
                    var ID = this["Worker_ID"];
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map: map,
                                    icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                    title: currVal
                                })


                                var link = $('<a href="#">' + currVal + '</a>')
                         .data('location', results[0].geometry.location);
                                $('#places').append($('<li id=Meow>').append(link));
                                link.on('click', function (event) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    google.maps.event.trigger(address[0], "click");
                                    infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                                    infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Worker/WorkerDetails?workerId=' + ID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                                    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                                });

                                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                                    $('#places').find('li a').css('display', function () {
                                        return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                      ? ''
                      : 'none';
                                    });
                                });



                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                                    return function () {
                                        infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                                        infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Worker/WorkerDetails?workerId=' + ID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                                        infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                                    }
                                })(marker, currVal));
                                address.push(marker);

                            }
                            else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                            }
                        }, 1000) 
                    });

                });
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
            });
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            initialize();
            codeAddress();
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Probably because the Results container isn't being revised correctly. This isn't really a Google Maps problem although you should probably also show the listener event that updates the Results.

Comment: @PaulGeronca stated in my codes already the listener event with this function `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {`